# System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTable without a value in asp.net mvc 4 application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I tried many times to do an extension method to customize a table , but i have some problem:

```
public static class HtmlElements
    {
        public static HtmlTable Table(this HtmlHelper ht, string classe, int num_rows, int num_columns, List<MvcHtmlString> content)
        {
            var table = new HtmlTable();
            table.Attributes.Add("class", classe);
            int index = -1;
            for (int j = 0; j < num_rows; j++)
            {
                HtmlTableRow row = new HtmlTableRow();
                for (int i = 0; i < num_columns; i++)
                {
                    // Create a new cell and add it to the Cells collection.
                    HtmlTableCell cell = new HtmlTableCell();
                    cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(content[++index].ToHtmlString()));
                    row.Cells.Add(cell);
                }
                table.Rows.Add(row);
            }
            return table;

        }

    }
```

**View**

```
@{
    List<MvcHtmlString> contenu = new List<MvcHtmlString>();
    MvcHtmlString hs = new MvcHtmlString("Description");
    contenu.Add(hs);
    hs = new MvcHtmlString("Client");
    contenu.Add(hs);
    hs = new MvcHtmlString("Statut du client");
    contenu.Add(hs);
    hs = new MvcHtmlString("Etat de test");
    contenu.Add(hs);
    hs = new MvcHtmlString("");
    contenu.Add(hs);    
    for (int i = Model[2] - 5; i < Model[2]; i++)
    {
    if(i < Model[1].Count)
    {
        hs = new MvcHtmlString(@Model[0][i].PDescription);
        contenu.Add(hs);
        hs = new MvcHtmlString(@Model[0][i].Nom_client);
        contenu.Add(hs);
        hs = new MvcHtmlString(@Model[0][i].Statut_client);
        contenu.Add(hs);
        hs = new MvcHtmlString(@Model[1][i]);
        contenu.Add(hs);


            if(@Model[1][i] == "Test non commencé"){
                hs = new MvcHtmlString(@Html.ActionLink("Lancer la première tentative du test", "First_Test_Attempt", new { id_project = @Model[0][i].Id_project }).ToHtmlString());
                contenu.Add(hs);

                     }

             if(@Model[1][i] == "Tentative finie"){
                 hs = new MvcHtmlString(@Html.ActionLink("Voir le résultat", "Display_Chef_Attempt", new { id_project = @Model[0][i].Id_project }).ToHtmlString());
                 contenu.Add(hs);

             }

            if (@Model[1][i] == "Test fini")
            {
                hs = new MvcHtmlString(@Html.ActionLink("Consulter le résulat final du test", "Final_consultation", new { id_project = @Model[0][i].Id_project }).ToHtmlString());
                contenu.Add(hs);
            }
            if (@Model[1][i] == "Test en cours") {
                hs = new MvcHtmlString(@Html.ActionLink("Consulter le résulat actuel du test", "Consultation", new { id_project = @Model[0][i].Id_project }).ToHtmlString());
                contenu.Add(hs);

                }


    }
    }
}

@Html.Table("table_data", 5, 5, contenu)
```

But i got  this line as a result :

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTable
```

What is the error that i commited? How can i fix my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you use ASP.NET MVC and Razor view engine. `HtmlTable` class is in `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls` (Web Forms).

I suggest that you [read](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs) and create an eligible table html extension helper.

Or simply make use of a `WebGrid`: [quick example](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=615).